# select an area of a scatter plot in javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, plot, selection, scatter-plot

I am trying to achieve the following with javascript:

1. draw a scatter plot with many (~10,000) points
2. allow the user to draw a curved shape on top of the plot to select a region (I am open to exactly how the shape is designed: an ellipse would be fine, or a polygon, or a path defined by bezier curves)
3. get a list of the points inside the selected area and do something with them.

Obviously, it is step 2 that is causing the problem. I have previously used jqplot to something similar to the above using a rectangular selection, but it is vital for the purposes of this project that the user be able to select an elliptical region.

Can anybody give any hint as to which javascript library would allow this?

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can create paths using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).  I would have though that the most difficult part of this would be the last, but I did find [this](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_point_in_polygon_path.html) (yes, I know it's VB, but it gives a basis that can be applied to JavaScript).